# Google Earth Engine subtraction (difference) of two geometries

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, google-earth-engine-python-api, differences, feature-collection

I am trying to create a feature collection containing the difference (subtraction) between a larger geometry (e.g. the state of California) and a few smaller geometries within the larger area (e.g. a few rectangles). I want to use the resulting feature collection to sample points only from the difference region. The area in blue in the below figure shows what I want to achieve from the subtraction of the state geometry from the two rectangles:

[image]

I tried to use the `ee.Geometry.difference` to return the subtraction of the larger and the smaller area (code below). However, I receive the error "EEException: Invalid GeoJSON geometry". I don't understand what is causing the error. Any idea how to do this?

```
california = ee.FeatureCollection("TIGER/2018/States").filter(ee.Filter.eq("NAME", 'California'))
california_geom = california.geometry()

rect1 = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-119.656567, 34.532314,-118.852982, 35.151939], None, False)
rect2 = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-118.523518, 36.699232,-117.884587, 37.218186], None, False)
features = [
  ee.Feature(rect1, {'name': 'rect1'}),
  ee.Feature(rect2, {'name': 'rect2'})
  ];
fc = ee.FeatureCollection(features);
rects_geom = fc.geometry()

geometryDifference = california_geom.difference({'right': rects_geom, 'maxError': 1});
```

Comment: Works for me: https://code.earthengine.google.com/153ebbebbe1efae97186dc671a8a08f1